# How can I access an existing Visualforce page in the Sandbox

Tags: apex, visualforce

I tried changing

> https://netops--contract.cs16.my.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/ui/ChatterPage

**to**

> https://netops--contract.cs16.my.salesforce.com/apex/**VISUAL FORCEPAGE NAME**

The page exists in my sandbox, but it throws this error:

> List Has no Rows for assignment to sObject

Comment: Is your page exist in SB? If yes then go to Setup>Develop > visualforce page > Select your page and preview

Comment: What do you mean by sb? @tushar Sharma

Comment: SB means sandbox.

Comment: And yeah it already exist in my Sandbox and it throws an error which is "List Has no Rows for assignment to sObject" so meaning there is something wrong with my component right?

Comment: @JMDF Please visit the [help] and read [ask]. The more specific you are, the better we are able to help you. In this case, you would be best served to **[edit]** your post to include the controller code involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the page it is just throwing an error.

Most likely the controller is using the standard controller or is grabbing a URL parameter to perform a query. You will need to review the code to see what is expected as well as the debug logs.

Trying accessing the page like this and see if that works:

```
xxxxx/apex/YourPageName?id=[recordId]
```

replacing the [recordId] with an actual ID of a record that the page is supposed to display.

Ultimately, to answer your question, you have accessed the page. Now you should be asking why is my code throwing that error